# do javascript arrays clone

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays as parameters and need to add each element from the `add` array to the `main` array, sort the `main`, then remove that element, and repeat (add the next element of `add` array to `main` array).

```
function twoArrays(main, add) {
  var tempArr =[];
  for(var i=0; i<main.length; i++){ 
    tempArr.push(main[i]);
  }

  for(var i=0; i<add.length; i++){ 
    main.push(add[i]);
    main = main.sort(function(a, b){return b - a}); 
    console.log(main); 
    main = [];
    main = tempArr; 
  } 

}


var main =[ 100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10 ] 
var add = [99, 44,33,22,9]
twoArrays(main, add);
```

My problem is this statement `main = tempArr;` is not working the way I think it should. I expect to delete main (`main = [];`), and then populate main with `tempArr` (`main = tempArr;`). However, I get the previous main, with `add` items in it, notice the 99, 44, 33, 22 as follows

```
 100,100,99,50,40,40,20,10
 100,100,50,44,40,40,20,10
 100,100,50,44,40,40,33,20,10
 100,100,50,44,40,40,33,22,20,10
 100,100,50,44,40,40,33,22,20,10,9
```

Comment: no, the *reference* to the "main" you passed in is lost when when you say `main = []` - after that, the `main` inside the function is unrelated to the `main` you passed in

Comment: Why don't you use `concat` and `sort`. 
`main = main.concat(add).sort(function(a, b){return b - a}); `
It's the same...

Comment: To cheaply clone an array `let x = [ ...y ];`

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you're losing reference to the original main when you do `main = []`. If you want to reset the array, and do a new transformation (add an element from `add` to `main`, sort, then reset), try this instead:

```js
function twoArrays(main, add) {
  for(var i=0; i<add.length; i++){ 
    let clone = [...main];
    clone.push(add[i]);
    clone.sort(function(a, b){return b - a}); 
    console.log(clone);
  } 
}


const main =[ 100, 100, 50, 40, 40, 20, 10 ] 
const add = [99, 44,33,22,9]
twoArrays(main, add);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `main = tempArr;` main and tempArr both point to the same array. To copy the tempArr in main, instead of `main = []; main = tempArr;` do `main = [..tempArr];`

Comment: Thank you. whats is [...] called, can you please point me to some resources online.

Comment: @allphonsk ````...```` is called the spread operator. It can also be used to copy objects.